# Searching for key string within target string in Python recursively

Tags: python, string, search, python-3.x

*The following is for Python 3.2.3.*

---

I would like to write a function that takes two arguments, a key string and a target string.  These function is to **recursively** determine (it must be recursive) the positions of the key string in the target string.

Currently, my code is as follows.

```
def posSubStringMatchRecursive(target,key):
    import string
    index=str.rfind(target, key)
    if index !=-1:
        print (index)
        target=target[:(index+len(key)-1)]
        posSubStringMatchRecursive(target,key)
```

The issue with this is that there is no way to store all the locations of the key string in the target string in a list as the numbers indicating the location will just be printed out.

So, my question is, *is there any way to change the code such that the positions of the key string in the target string can be stored in a list*?

---

### Example Output

```
countSubStringMatchRecursive ('aatcgdaaaggraaa', 'aa')

13
12
7
6
0
```

---

### Edit

The following code seems to work without the issue in Ashwini's code. Thanks, Lev.

```
def posSubStringMatchRecursive(target,key):
    import string
    index=str.rfind(target, key)
    if index ==-1:
        return []
    else:
        target=target[:(index+len(key)-1)]
        return ([index] + posSubStringMatchRecursive(target,key))
```

Comment: Why does it have to be recursive? If this is a homework question, please [tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework) it as such

Comment: i have a nice and clean iterative method, am just wondering whether you can recursively generate a list as the runtime for the recursive version seems to be faster (for small samples)

Comment: to be honest, the questions come from [link]http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/assignments/pset3.pdf but it doesn't happen to be my homework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def posSubStringMatchRecursive(target,key,res):
    import string
    index=str.rfind(target, key)
    if index !=-1:

        target=target[:(index+len(key)-1)]
        res.append(index) #append the index to the list res, 
        return posSubStringMatchRecursive(target,key,res) #Use return here when calling recursively else your program will return None, and also pass res to the function
    else:
        return res

 print(posSubStringMatchRecursive('aatcgdaaaggraaa', 'aa',[]))#pass a empty list to the function
print(posSubStringMatchRecursive('aatcgdaaaggraaa', 'a',[]))
```

**output:**`

```
[13, 12, 7, 6, 0]`
[14, 13, 12, 8, 7, 6, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Now try to call it again :) Repeat the `print` line, for example.

Comment: @LevLevitsky As I mentioned it's acts as a static variable, and will persist value with every call, so it's good only for one time call.

Comment: @LevLevitsky I edited my solution,to make it work for multiple calls.

Answer (score 0):

Since it suspiciously resembles a homework question, here's an example of a recursive function  that returns a list:

```
In [1]: def range_rec(limit):
    if limit == 0:
        return []
    else:
        return ([limit-1] + range_rec(limit-1)[::-1])[::-1]
   ...: 

In [2]: range_rec(10)
Out[2]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: i've worked on your code and edited my own question. thanks for the direction.

Comment: i'd up-vote your answer if I could, but unfortunately I don't have enough rep. sorry!